# Rails 4.2 get delayed job id from active job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, rails-activejob

Any idea how to get the `Delayed::Job` id from the ActiveJob enqueuing? When I enqueue a job I get back an instance of `ActiveJob::Base` with a `@job_id`, but that job id seems to be internal to ActiveJob. My best guess so far is just to walk down the most recently created jobs:

```
active_job_id = GenerateReportJob.perform_later(self.id).job_id
delayed_job = Delayed::Job.order(id: :desc).limit(5).detect do |job|
  YAML.load(job.handler).job_data['job_id'] == active_job_id
end
```

but that seems all kinds of hacky. Kind of surprised ActiveJob isn't returning the ID from `Delayed::Job`, especially since that is what is explicitly returned when the job gets enqueued.

== EDIT

Looks like I'm not the only one (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18821)

Comment: Ah, but then some might argue that needing to get the job id is "all kinds of hacky" too! Out of curiosity, and because it might open the door to an alternative approach, why do you need the job id?

Comment: It's for the ability to cancel reports before they run while they're in the queue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case anyone finds this in the future: Rails just accepted a patch to allow you to get this id from provider_job_id in Rails 5. You can get it to work with a patch like

```
ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
  def enqueue(job)
    provider_job = super
    job.provider_job_id = provider_job.id
    provider_job
  end

  def enqueue_at(job, timestamp)
    provider_job = super
    job.provider_job_id = provider_job.id
    provider_job
  end
end)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! Where would one put this code, though?

Comment: @Alexander Typically this would go into an initializer. Something like config/initializers/delayed_job.rb

Comment: Before that patch came in, I ran into this issue, and made a gem to query job status via ActiveJob: https://github.com/cdale77/active_job_status

Comment: In addition to this, you'll likely need to either add `attr_accessor :provider_job_id` to ApplicationJob (if you're doing this yet), or to each of your Job classes. Adding @kddeisz's code to an initialiser works really well.

Comment: In case it's still not clear enough for anyone, in Rails 5 you can just say @job.provider_job_id

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the answer of Beguene and some reverse engineering of the Rails 5 ActiveJob code, I have made it work with Rails 4.2 by

1) adding following code in `lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb` or `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` (both locations have worked):

```
# file: lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb
module ActiveJob
  module Core
    # ID optionally provided by adapter
    attr_accessor :provider_job_id
  end

  module QueueAdapters
    class DelayedJobAdapter
      class << self
        def enqueue(job) #:nodoc:
          delayed_job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(JobWrapper.new(job.serialize), queue: job.queue_name)
          job.provider_job_id = delayed_job.id
          delayed_job
        end

        def enqueue_at(job, timestamp) #:nodoc:
          delayed_job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(JobWrapper.new(job.serialize), queue: job.queue_name, run_at: Time.at(timestamp))
          job.provider_job_id = delayed_job.id
          delayed_job
        end
      end
      class JobWrapper #:nodoc:
        attr_accessor :job_data

        def initialize(job_data)
          @job_data = job_data
        end

        def perform
          Base.execute(job_data)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `attr_accessor :provider_job_id` statement is needed in Rails 4.2, since it is used in the enqueue method and is not yet defined in 4.2.

Then we can make use of it like follows:

2) define our own ActiveJob class:

```
# file: app/jobs/my_job.rb
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(object, performmethod = method(:method))
    # Do something later
      returnvalue = object.send(performmethod)
      returnvalue
    end

  end
end
```

3) Now we can create a new job anywhere in the code:

```
job = MyJob.perform_later(Myobject, "mymethod")
```

This will put the method `Myobject.mymethod` into the queue.

4) The code in 1) helps us to find the Delayed Job that is associated with our job:

```
delayed_job = Delayed::Job.find(job.provider_job_id)
```

5) finally, we can do, whatever we need to do with the delayed_job, e.g. delete it:

```
delayed_job.delete
```

Note: in Rails 5, step 1) will not be needed anymore, since the exact same code is integral part of Rails 5.

Comment: @kddeisz: I have tested the answer of Beguene only (because it is closer to the Rails 5 code, and your answer was too clever for me to understand; but it looks great!). In Beguene's answer, only a tiny ingredient was missing: the ```attr_accessor :provider_job_id``` statement. The better option would have been to add a comment to Beguene's answer, but, since I am new to stackoverflow and have no reputation, I did not have the permission to add comments. Therefore, I figured, it makes sense to answer the question with all ingredients I needed to make it work.

Comment: This is nice, if you want to get the provider id (delayed job id) in the `enqueue` callbacks, but, it does not give you the id at the time of perform (in the `perform` callbacks)

Answer (score 2):

I made it work in Rails 4.2 using the new patch from Rails 5 like this:

create the file `lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb`

```
module ActiveJob
  module QueueAdapters
    class DelayedJobAdapter
      class << self
        def enqueue(job) #:nodoc:
          delayed_job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(JobWrapper.new(job.serialize), queue: job.queue_name)
          job.provider_job_id = delayed_job.id
          delayed_job
        end

        def enqueue_at(job, timestamp) #:nodoc:
          delayed_job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(JobWrapper.new(job.serialize), queue: job.queue_name, run_at: Time.at(timestamp))
          job.provider_job_id = delayed_job.id
          delayed_job
        end
      end

      class JobWrapper #:nodoc:
        attr_accessor :job_data

        def initialize(job_data)
          @job_data = job_data
        end

        def perform
          Base.execute(job_data)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the job from the queue if it is cancelled you could model a cancellation of the job itself.

Then, when you come to run the `GenerateReportJob` you can first check for a cancellation of the report. If there is one then you can destroy the cancellation record and drop out of the report generation. If there is no cancellation then you can carry on as normal.

Comment: Yes, I could. But... the point of using Delayed::Job is that it's a descendant of ActiveRecord::Base. It has an id on the table - so it seems silly to create another column/model/object/concept of cancellation when before I integrated with active job I was able to just get the id.

Comment: Anyway, the point of asking this question was just to see if anyone knew how to get the ID. Looking here though: (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb#L74) seems to indicate that that job will be returned either way, as opposed to the delayed job. And so I will hack.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I appreciate I was answering a slightly different question.

Comment: No problem! I appreciate the timely response!