# Get Id of created Job in Delayed Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am adding some emails in the queue using Delayed Jobs. The way I create a job is given below:

```
EventNotifications.reminder("email", "name", id).deliver_later
```

where EventNotifications is the class and reminder is the method inside it.

This creates a job in delayed_jobs table but I want to get the Id of the job created as I have some custom field inside the delayed_jobs table that I want to update.

What I currently get after running the above line is:

```
#<ActionMailer::DeliveryJob:0x00000005eb22d8 @arguments=["EventNotifications", "reminder", "deliver_now", "email", "name", 12], @job_id="6a549235-e8c1-407b-ac75-be8736559eaa", @queue_name="mailers">
```

This does not have the Id of the job that was created. How do I get that Id?

Comment: Since you're in Rails 4.2 and not yet Rails 5, you won't be able to use `.provider_job_id` yet. But you can check [these "hacks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855768/rails-4-2-get-delayed-job-id-from-active-job)

Comment: Whether you need object id or worker id?

Comment: @Jay Thank you. I'll look into your answer

Comment: @NatarajaB I need the object Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bypass ActiveJob and use the DelayedJob API directly. This has the downside of not abstracting your job system away. You can do something like this:

```
job = EventNotifications.delay.reminder("email", "name", id)
```

At that point, you have access to `job.id`.

Comment: This method works for me but can you please explain what do you mean by this: "This has the downside of not abstracting your job system away"

Comment: When you use ActiveJob, it lets you write your code in such a way that it's not tied to any specific job backend. For example, if you're using delayed_job right now, you may want to switch to resque (a different jobs backend) later. With ActiveJob, this is really easy.

With the code I gave you, you'd have to go back and change it when you switch to resque.